# AllShare Cast / Screen Cast not working on certain phones

Tags: android, casting, share, screencast

I went to the Samsung website and downloaded the Media Control SDK package.
When I used the AllShare Cast Video Player on my Galaxy S3 Android 4.3, my Smart TV (in the same network) showed up in the AllShare Cast list.

However,

When I used the same app on my rooted Galaxy Note 2 Android 4.1.1,
my Smart TV(in the same network) didn't show up on the AllShare Cast list.

Code:

```
public class DevicePicker extends Fragment implements OnClickListener,SmcDeviceFinder.StatusListener, SmcDeviceFinder.DeviceListener {


    public interface DevicePickerResult {

        void onDeviceSelected(SmcDevice device);

        /**
         * User clicked to disable AllShare
         */
        void onAllShareDisabled();
    }

    /**
     * The type of device we are interested in
     */
    private int mType = SmcDevice.TYPE_AVPLAYER;

    /**
     * Listener to be notified of events
     */
    private DevicePickerResult mPickerListener;

    /**
     * Device finder instance
     */
    private SmcDeviceFinder smcDeviceFinder;

    /**
     * The ImageView displaying AllShare icon
     */
    private ImageView mIcon;

    /**
     * Flag indicating if AllShare is currently active
     */
    private boolean mActive;

    private String mDeviceId;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Set view, remember ImageView for icon and setup onclick listener.
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.device_picker, container, false);
        mIcon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.devicePickerIcon);
        mIcon.setOnClickListener(this);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        /*
        if(savedInstanceState!=null){
            mDeviceId = savedInstanceState.getString("deviceId");
        }
        */
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    }

    public void setDeviceType(int type) {
        mType = type;
    }

    public void setDeviceSelectedListener(DevicePickerResult listener) {
        mPickerListener = listener;
        restoreDevice();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        // The service provider needs to be created after device type is set
        // It could also be created in onStart or onResume, but we the sooner
        // we create it, the sooner we get devices.
        SmcDeviceFinder df = new SmcDeviceFinder(getActivity());
        df.setStatusListener(this);
        df.start();

    }


    private void restoreDevice(){
        if(smcDeviceFinder != null && mDeviceId!=null && mPickerListener != null) {
            SmcDevice SmcDevice_ = smcDeviceFinder.getDevice(mType, mDeviceId);
            if(SmcDevice_!=null){
                mPickerListener.onDeviceSelected(SmcDevice_);
                setActive(true);
            }
        }
    }

    public void setActive(boolean newState) {
        if (newState == mActive) {
            // No change in state, do nothing
            return;
        }
        mActive = newState;
        mIcon.setImageResource(
                newState ?
                        R.drawable.allshare_icons_active :
                        R.drawable.allshare_icons_inactive);
        updateButtonCounter();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v != mIcon) {
            return;
        }

        if(smcDeviceFinder != null) {

            int numDevices = smcDeviceFinder.getDeviceList(mType).size();

            // If no devices found, try refreshing the list.
            if (numDevices == 0) {
                smcDeviceFinder.rescan();
            }

            // If we are already active, disable allshare
            if (mActive) {
                setActive(false);
                if (mPickerListener != null) {
                    mPickerListener.onAllShareDisabled();
                }
                return;
            }
        }

        // Devices are available, and we are not connected
        // Ask user to select device
        showPickerDialog();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        if (smcDeviceFinder != null) {
            smcDeviceFinder.stop();
            smcDeviceFinder = null;
        }
        super.onDetach();
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // These methods handle device finder start hide event.
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    @Override
    public void onStarted(SmcDeviceFinder deviceFinder, int error) {
        if (error == Smc.SUCCESS) {
            smcDeviceFinder = deviceFinder;
            smcDeviceFinder.setDeviceListener(mType, this);
            smcDeviceFinder.rescan();
            updateButtonCounter();
            restoreDevice();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopped(SmcDeviceFinder deviceFinder) {
        if (smcDeviceFinder == deviceFinder) {
            smcDeviceFinder.setDeviceListener(mType, null);
            smcDeviceFinder.setStatusListener(null);
            smcDeviceFinder = null;
        }
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // These methods handle devices appearing and disappearing in network.
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    @Override
    public void onDeviceAdded(SmcDeviceFinder deviceFinder, SmcDevice smcDevice) {
        // We aren't interested in individual devices, only in their number
        updateButtonCounter();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDeviceRemoved(SmcDeviceFinder deviceFinder, SmcDevice smcDevice, int error) {
        // We aren't interested in individual devices, only in their number
        updateButtonCounter();
        //if current device has been removed
        if (smcDevice.getId().equals(mDeviceId)) {
            setActive(false);
            if (mPickerListener != null) {
                mPickerListener.onAllShareDisabled();
            }
        }
    }



    /**
     * Methods that selects which icon to display, based on number of
     * available devices in network.
     */
    private void updateButtonCounter() {
        if (smcDeviceFinder != null) {
            int numDevices =
                smcDeviceFinder.getDeviceList(mType).size();

            mIcon.getDrawable().setLevel(numDevices);
            if (numDevices==0) {
                setActive(false);
            }
        }
    }

    public void showPickerDialog() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DeviceSelectActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("deviceType", mType);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }

    /**
     * Callback when user has selected device in device select activity.
     */
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            mDeviceId = data.getStringExtra("deviceId");
            int type = data.getIntExtra("deviceType", -1);

            if (smcDeviceFinder != null && mPickerListener != null) {
                SmcDevice device = smcDeviceFinder.getDevice(type, mDeviceId);
                if(device!=null){
                    mPickerListener.onDeviceSelected(device);
                    setActive(true);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The wifi was turned on.

**Can someone please help me?**

There are apps that can even see my Apple TV device (my app can't even see this Apple TV device on the AllShare Cast list)

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, the AllShare casting is built on top of Miracast. That feature was included in Android 4.2 for devices with the necessary hardware support, which would explain why your Note 2 running 4.1.1 has issues.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, but that's not true.  Their site says "Devices with Android 4.0 Ice Cream Sandwich (API level 14) or higher"  Link:  http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy#media-control    thanks a lot

Comment: Now that you mention it I think the Miracast support was added to the AllShare dongle/device via a software update. Have Samsung really not updated the Note 2 past 4.1.1 though?